# Autofac IOC: Why circular dependency between services detected in runtime?

Tags: service, interface, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm using `Autofac IOC` in my Asp.Net MVC Application. I have seen a circular dependency between services detected in run time (even not detected in building/rebuilding project). Why this happen in run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac is not a compiler or compiler plugin. It is a *library* that uses *reflection* to gather information only available *at runtime* to build object graphs, and it only does so when you start your application.

If you want compiler support: don't use a DI Container, but revert to using [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), which means you build your object graphs by hand (using `new` statements) inside the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Comment: I generally understand your answer that autofac is no compile, which makes sense. Nevertheless, there is a Build-Method which is called to generate a container which could already perform such checks in advance while building the dependency tree. Is there something like that available?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd expect that Autofac contains some cyclic dependency checking during its build process. It could be, though,  that it is unable to find all cycles. I know that Simple Injector finds most of those cycles when you call Verify, but that isn't of use to you if you're using Autofac.

Comment: I’m not stuck with autofac, but I’d prefer to use that container. I just gave that a try but unfortunately there is no circular dependency checking when calling „build“- at least it didn’t find mine using two components which depend on each other using constructor injection. Is there maybe a flag which can be set or an explicit „verify“ method which could be called?

Comment: You should to consult the documentation to see whether there is such flag  but I doubt there is. Likely the build process does little verification. You might want to consider writing a unit test that iterates Autofac's registrations and tries to resolve them.